# How to push the values in multidimensional array from JS

Tags: javascript

I am having one multidimensional array  in JS, on that name is same we need to take the particular `id` and push into new array, how we can achieve this please any one help me

```
    var array1 = [
    {"id":"1", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"2", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"3", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"4", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"5", "name" : "4"},
];
```

> Expected answer

```
var final = [
  { "name" : "2", "IDS" : ["1", "2"] },
  { "name" : "3", "IDS" : ["3", "4"] },
  { "name" : "4", "IDS" : ["5"] }
];
```

Comment: you can use ES6 latest functionality *map* and *filter* function from my post as well. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` & `findIndex`. In reduce callback function check if the accumulator array have an object with specific name which can be done using `findIndex`. If the element with name exist then update the IDS array else push an object in the accumulator array

```js
var array1 = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "3"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "4"
  },
];


let newArr = array1.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let findName = acc.findIndex((item) => {
    return item.name === curr.name;
  })

  if (findName === -1) {
    acc.push({
      name: curr.name,
      IDS: [curr.id]

    })
  } else {
    acc[findName].IDS.push(curr.id)
  }


  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array1 = [
    {"id":"1", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"2", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"3", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"4", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"5", "name" : "4"},
];

var newArray = [];
array1.map((data,index) =>{
     const isExist = newArray.filter(m => m.name === data.name);
     if(isExist.length > 0){
        isExist[0].IDS.push(data.id);
     }else{
          newArray.push({ name : data.name , IDS : [data.id]});
      }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [
    {"id":"1", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"2", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"3", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"4", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"5", "name" : "4"},
];

const newObj = array1.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (acc[val.name]) {
    acc[val.name].ids.push(val.id);
  } else {
    acc[val.name] = {
      name: val.name,
      ids: [val.id]
    }
  } 
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(newObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple loop over the array will be enough:

```js
var array1 = [
    {"id":"1", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"2", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"3", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"4", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"5", "name" : "4"},
];

let result = [];

array1.forEach(elem => {
  let curr = result.filter(r => r.name == elem.name);
  if(curr.length == 1) {
    curr[0].ID.push(elem.id);
  } else {
    result.push({
      name: elem.name,
      ID: [elem.id]
    });
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.reduce() :

```js
var array1 = [
    {"id":"1", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"2", "name" : "2"},
    {"id":"3", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"4", "name" : "3"},
    {"id":"5", "name" : "4"},
];

array1 = array1.reduce(function(acc,current){
   let existing = acc.find(item=> item.name==current.name);
if(existing){
  existing.ids.push(current.id);
}else{
  acc.push({name:current.name,ids:[current.id]});
}
return acc
},[]);

console.log(array1)
```